# Как переразметить жесткий диск?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, dual-boot

При установке убунту, я "отрезал" место от винды для убунты (разметка диска). Я тогда пожадничал и теперь места на убунту не хватает. Вопрос: можно ли БЕЗ переустановки убунту "отрезать" еще?

Answer (score 1):

Можно, отрежьте в винде от своего виндового раздела (это можно сделать через **управление компьютером** -> **управление дисками**, просто уменьшив виндовый раздел). И в убунте запустите **gparted** и измените размер раздела убунты.

Answer (score 1):

Возьмите Acronis True Image 2011, сделайте backup раздела с Ubuntu (и раздела с виндой, если в ней толк ещё есть... ;-) Скопируйте куда-нибудь левые данные, если такие имеются...
Затем снова разбейте диск, посадите сначала винду, а затем убунту...

Потом возьмите лайфсиди, с которого убунту ставили и там, в консоли, выполните следующие команды, а для этого идите сюда: http://ubuntologia.ru/grub-mbr-windows#grub.

Метод мучительный, но зато у вас сохранённые копии Windows и Ubuntu + маленький опыт. )

Answer (score 0):

PartitionMagic поможет переразбить диск, данные лучше куда-нибудь скопировать.

Comment: Что лучше: 1. удалить все, поставить заново ubuntu поверх windows, 2. удалить только windows?

Comment: У вас Partition Magic полноценный? Триальная версия не все может.
Плюс, я уже предупреждал, что надо бы забекапить раздел с виндой.
На самом деле, все зависит от того, как у вас разбит диск, одного количества разделов недостаточно. А в целом, я бы лучше для убунты взял другой винчестер.

Comment: Partition Magic полный.
короче ладно. пофиг.
переустановлю ubuntu, а венду в топку

Comment: Я теперь даже рад, что венда полетела =)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем отрезание, но все же.
Как вариант, можно просто смонтировать виндовый раздел и использовать его диски из убунты.
Я так использую диск со всякими сырцами, удобно по учебе, из любой ОС на ноуте можно достучаться до нужной информации, будь то исходник или какая книга.